# How to prove or disprove matrices $A$ and $B$ commute iff $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove or show the statement is false with counterexample:

Square matrices $A$ and $B$ commute if and only if $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$

Now, this is a biconditional statement, so we must prove $X=>Y$ $\land$ $Y=>X$

I managed to prove $X=>Y$: if the statement $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$ holds, the two matices must commute but how do you prove, or disprove $Y=>X$: if matrices commute the statement $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$ holds?

Here is the part of the proof:

$(A-B)_{ik}=a_{ik}b_{jk}$

$(A+B)_{kj}=a_{kj}b_{kj}$

$(A-B)_{ik}(A+B)_{kj}$
=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}(A-B)_{ik}(A+B)_{kj}$

=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}(a_{ik}-b_{ik})(a_{kj}+b_{kj})$

=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}a_{ik}a_{kj}+a_{ik}b_{kj}-n_{ik}a_{kj}-b_{ik}b_{kj}$

=$\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}a_{ik}a_{kj}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}a_{ik}b_{kj}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}-b_{ik}a_{kj}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^\mathbb{n}-b_{ik}b_{kj}$

=$A^2_{ij}-B^2_{ij}+AB_{ij}-BA_{ij}$

From this we can see if the statement $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$ holds, $AB_{ij}-BA_{ij}=0$ which is true only if matrices $A$ and $B$ commute.

**How would you now prove or disproove that if matrices $A$ and $B$ commute** $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$ **must be the case?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking way too overcomplicated. We have
$$(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2.$$
Both directions follow at once.

Comment: I just realised the statement in the title is not the same as the one in the body. Can the OP clarify which one is meant?

Comment: What part is not the same?

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 Are we supposed to show $AB=BA$ if and only if $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-B^2$ or $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2+B^2$?

Comment: My mistake… I didn't notice the mistake. I corrected the mistake.

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 Okay, then my argument applies indeed. Can you see why?

Comment: Ok, so I overcomplicated the proof by proving the distributive property withing my proof. I could've just used the letters without the subscripts? And when we get to $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$ we can prove the statement in both directions, that is: If the statement $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$ holds, the two matrices must commute and if they commute, the statement $(A+B)(A-B)=A^2-AB+BA-B^2$ holds? Does this constitute as valid proof?

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 Yes, that is correct. Once you have the fact that matrix multiplication distributes over addition, there's no need to reason in terms of the individual elements (the subscripts) anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I think I understand everything with regards to this proof now. Thank you once more.

Comment: @ToTheSpace2 Glad to help.